# What is the difference between getView() and getActivity()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, getview

What is the difference between `getView()` and `getActivity()`?

I have used both methods but don't understand the basic difference even methodology of usage are also same in android:

```
ListView deliverItemList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list);
ListView deliverItemList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list);
```

I have assumed that `getView()` may produce `NullPointerException`, share your knowledge with me and which method is recommended?

Answer (score 7):

`getActivity()` returns the `Activity` hosting the `Fragment`, while `getView()` returns the view you inflated and *returned* by `onCreateView`. The latter returns a value `!= null` only after `onCreateView` returns

Comment: so, i have to use getActivity() or getView() in Fragment ?

Comment: 99% of the time getView. Or if you can, override `onViewCreated ` and use the former parameter  VIew, to look for your views

Comment: in my case I override onActivityCreated

Comment: Method invocation 'getView().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: check `if (getView() != null) {  getView().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list) ; }`

Answer (score 6):

From android docs:

> getActivity() returns the Activity this fragment is currently
>   associated with, and getView() returns the root view for the
>   fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater,
>   ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.

So, in your case, by the following line of code:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list);
```

you are searching for the view in your fragment, but using the following line of code:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list);
```

you are searching for the view in your activity hosting your fragment.

About your question of which one to use, it depends. If you are trying to inflate fragment, you need to inflate your xml in onCreateView, and using that inflated view you search for your views like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.view_id);
}
```

Comment: Method invocation 'getView().findViewById(R.id.load_item_list)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: yes, if you call getView() in onCreateView(), it will return null. You can either call getView() in the method onViewCreated(), or you can do the following in your onCreateView() function: View v = inflater.inflate(your_fragment_layout_id, container, false); ListView lv = v.findViewById(R.id.load_item_list);