# Android - View instance gets null on screen rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using Kotlin Android Extension to access view directly by their id.
I have a progress bar which I access directly in fragment using id i.e progress_bar

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"/>
```

In fragment, I am showing and hiding it with this code

```
progress_bar.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

It is working perfectly until I rotate the screen. After that, it throws the exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: progress_bar must not be null.

The variable gets null on screen rotation. How to solve this problem?

Fragment code

```
class SingleAppFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var appName: String

companion object {
    fun newInstance(appName: String = ""): SingleAppFragment {
        val fragment = SingleAppFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(Constants.EXTRA_APP_NAME, appName)
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}

private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    appName = if (arguments != null && !arguments.getString(Constants.EXTRA_APP_NAME).isEmpty()) {
        arguments.getString(Constants.EXTRA_APP_NAME)
    } else {
        Constants.APP_NAME_FACEBOOK
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_single_app, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initView()
    setEventListeners()
}

private fun initView() {
    var canShowSnackBar = true

    web_single_app.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            showHideProgressBar(true)
            canShowSnackBar = true
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            showHideProgressBar(false)
        }

        override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
            web_single_app.stopLoading()
            if (canShowSnackBar) {
                mListener?.onErrorWebView()
                canShowSnackBar = false
            }
        }
    }
    web_single_app.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    web_single_app.loadUrl(Constants.APP_NAME_URL_MAP[appName])
}

private fun setEventListeners() {
    back_web_control.setOnClickListener({
        web_single_app.goBack()
    })
}

fun showHideProgressBar(visible: Boolean) {
    progress_bar_web_control.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}

fun loadUrl(appName: String) {
    web_single_app.loadUrl(Constants.APP_NAME_URL_MAP[appName])
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = context
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    mListener = null
}

interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    fun onErrorWebView()
}
}
```

---

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Start Activity
2. Fragment get loaded
3. At Fragment load, I load an URL and show a progress bar
4. At loading the URL I rotate the phone and the progress bar variable gets null

Comment: In which method do you get the progress_bar by Id? Please consider the fragment state lifecycle. Maybe you try to load it when the view is not ready yet. Refer to here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @BrunoBieri I am calling in the onCreateView() but before the "return view" statement. Hence, the variable didn't get assigned. Now, I am accessing the "progress_bar" like "view.progress_bar" and the problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: You should be doing this in `onViewCreated`

Comment: Thanks, @MichałBaran, I will follow this

Comment: @PalkeshJain I converted my comment to an answer. May you can mark it as an answer for your question.

Comment: @PalkeshJain from your comment it's not clear if the problem is solved. Do you still face the issue?

Comment: @BrunoBieri yes, still facing the issue. Now, I am calling the view methods in onViewCreated(). The crashing scenario: I load an URL and then immediately rotate the screen.

Comment: @PalkeshJain as written please provide the code when you **assign** the `progress_bar` variable in your code.

Comment: @BrunoBieri I have added the whole fragment code, please check. Thanks

Comment: @PalkeshJain I can't help you with it. You haven't posted the code where you **assign** the `progress_bar` variable. From the code you posted it seems the variable is not assgined at all.

Comment: @BrunoBieri the variable is assigned by kotlin android extension, in which we don't need to initialize the view variables. My problem is solved by setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: @PalkeshJain, if you have enough (mana) rate, you can accept or increase an answer that helped you. In my case I also faced this problem, but in a large project with coroutines, and `retainInstance = true` didn't help. In a new project with a fragment (without `retainInstance = true`) it doesn't reproduce.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this bug happens from time to time. Of course, `onViewCreated()` is a good method to place your code in. But sometimes it's strangely not enough. And `setRetainInstance(true)` may help, may not. So sometimes this helps: access your `View`s with a `view` variable. You can even access them inside `onCreateView()`. You can use `?.` for a guarantee that an application won't crash (of course, some views won't update in this case). If you wish to get `context`, use `view.context`.

In my case this bug reproduced only in Kotlin coroutines.

```
private fun showProgress(view: View) {
    view.progressBar?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

private fun hideProgress(view: View) {
    view.progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Then in code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    showData(view)
}

private fun showData(view: View) {
    showProgress(view)
    adapter = SomeAdapter()
    adapter.setItems(items)
    val divider = SomeItemDecoration(view.context)
    view.recycler_view?.run {
        addItemDecoration(divider)
        adapter = this@SomeFragment.adapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
        setHasFixedSize(true)
    }
    hideProgress(view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In which method do you get the `progress_bar` by Id?

Please consider the fragment state [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Maybe you try to load it when the view is not ready yet.

Ensure your `progress_bar` variable is assigned only after the view is ready. For example in the 
[`onViewCreated`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) method.

See here the [official Android lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

[image: Official Android lifecycle]

**Update**

As @CoolMind pointed out the diagram doesn't show the method `onViewCreated`.

The complete Android Activity/Fragment lifecycle can be found [here](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle):

[image: The complete Android Activity/Fragment lifecycle]

Comment: I have updated my question, you can better understand the scenario now.

Comment: You are right, `onViewCreated()` is a right place to access views, but your scheme doesn't contain it. :)

Comment: @CoolMind you're right. I've checked the sources and it seems it really not there. Check here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) and here (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: @BrunoBieri, I agree with you. FYI, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105513/edittext-view-returns-null.

Comment: @CoolMind thank you!! I wasn't aware of that. Updated the answer.

Comment: @BrunoBieri, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add retain intance true to the fragment so that it will not be destroyed when an orientation changes occurs

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    retainInstance=true
}
```

Also do a null check using safe call operator before accessing views

```
fun showHideProgressBar(visible: Boolean) {
    progress_bar_web_control?.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```